# Spring MVC - Downloading PDF using outputstream & HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, servlets, jasper-reports

I'm trying to write a Controller that downloads a pdf file on the browser. I am using Jasper Reports to generate the pdf file in Java code (fully tested and it works perfectly). Now, I want to get the output stream that is being written by Jasper Reports and download it on the browser. However, when I click the button (which sends a POST to my mapped controller method), no download happens, and no error occurs.

Relevant code :

```
@RequestMapping("/vm/dormant/pdfReport")
public void exportIdleVMReport(@RequestParam(value = "sdkUrl", required = true) String sdkUrl, 
        @RequestParam(value = "threshold", required = false, defaultValue = "30") int threshold,
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    try {
        //Generated jasperPrint here
        .....

        //OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ServletOutputStream outputStream=response.getOutputStream();
        /* Write content to PDF file */
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outputStream);
        response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "employee.pdf");
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        outputStream.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        System.out.println("File Generated");

    } catch (RemoteException | MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JRException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I successfully reach "File Generated" without any errors, I also generate the file using an absolute path and that works just fine. I simply don't get any file download on the browser when I click on the button. Since there is no error either on the server or browser, I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

EDIT : 
I don't know if this matters, but I should add that this is an old project in my company. The project uses spring framework dependencies that are version 4.3.0.RELEASE, javax servlet is version 3.0.1.

EDIT 2 : Tested by changing frontend code to reach /vm/dormant/pdfReport directly, and it works! If HttpServletResponse is supposed to send a response back to the URL from where I sent the AJAX, why isn't it working properly?

Comment: "frontend code to reach /vm/dormant/pdfReport directly" what does that mean? Why wouldn't it go there directly?

Comment: @codebrane it means instead of using ajax to do a POST to /vm/dormant/pdfReport I just straight up built the URL string with the parameters and made the button open a new window to that URL. Now when I click the button, the page loads for a while, then downloads the file and automatically closes the tab. I changed nothing else but the frontend code. Why doesn't the servlet response work when I send the AJAX, but works just fine if I directly visit the URL?

Comment: That sounds like you're using GET with the button but POST with the Ajax call. There may be subtle differences. I've updated the answer to explicity use POST as the method to see if that helps the Ajax call. As it stands, the method will handle both but it's good practice to be explicit about the method

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the output is being written before the response is set up. I don't know what Jasper does but this might be a more likely order:

```
response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "employee.pdf");
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
ServletOutputStream outputStream=response.getOutputStream();
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outputStream);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

plus it's good practice to be explicit with the request method:

@RequestMapping("/vm/dormant/pdfReport", method = POST)

If the `@RequestParam` are being handled slightly differently between `GET` and `POST` that may explain why the report generation code doesn't work for `POST` but does work for `GET` as per your description.

Comment: Tried this. Still doesn't work. Added additional info in OP.